# How can we check whether wireless extensions were enabled in kernel or not through kernel image

Tags: linux-kernel, wifi, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

How can we check whether wireless extensions are enabled in the kernel or not through kernel image?

Consider I loaded the Zimage onto a platform and wanted to know whether the wireless extensions(Ex : CONFIG_WEXT...) were enabled or not in the kernel without referring to kernel source code or kernel .config

Is there any way to check this on a platform where we don't have kernel source code and only kernel image

Comment: At run-time, you could check whether the /proc/net/wireless file exists. If you are not running the kernel, but have access to its symbol table, you could look for specific symbols such as `wireless_send_event`. Of course, you ought to be able to get the source used to build the kernel under the terms of the GNU Public Licence.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to build the linux kernel such that the resultant image actually has the kconfig you used embedded in it. Check out [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381724/313887) question on a different stackexchange for more information.